# AWS VPC (Virtual Private Cloud), rapidly increasing expenses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cost-explorer, cost-optimization

Almost 3 years now we had a AWS  account  with a lot of ECS Fargate services.

Each service is using only on AWS Default VPC, and at  the time, we were never charged on that.

On 2024 February 01, we got charged by the AWS, Each Day more than 7 dollars without any changes on the system, and now i am not able to figure out what is actually happening.
[image: aws charg]

I looked after everything, but it comes from nowhere, and i have no clue what is happening.
I am not able to delete all the default VPC.

Do you faced something similar?
There is a change in AWS ecosystem?, and how they manage VPC costing?

I try to decrease the cost of AWS VPC,  what is happening on our billing dashboard, and try to understand and avoid to the same happen again.

Comment: You can raise a support ticket to AWS in the AWS console. The support engineer can help you figure out how the AWS vpc costing works

Comment: This is the reason: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/ Also, if you looked at the current bill, you can see the breakdown of what specifically you are being charged for.

Comment: Are you really using 60 public IPv4 IP addresses?

Comment: For the target groups, we use a lot of target groups with ecs, up to 60 for connect to  a load balancer, and each of them is have an IP address, so yes.

Comment: I think i will be able to solve the this, thank you for pointing out to changed on AWS, and what is can be the issue! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible reason is the price for IPV4 addresses. They were free but from february 2024 (Effective from February 1, 2024) [AWS is charging for ipv4 addresses](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/).

To reduce this cost you can use a NAT gateway and use one IP and keep the instances private that can be kept private.

Comment: Yes, this Change was part of my probleme, i will be able to solve, thank you!

Comment: No wonder why my bill went up in February 2024. Thanks for confirming this Ashraf. Do you have any links/tips for an alternative setup?

Comment: @ken, usually we should use less public IP addresses, and use IPV6 where we can. We can keep a NAT gateway for the instances on a VPC to communicate with outside world, and only that NAT will have a public IP.